# Kineticjs Dragend - How to Store results of getPosition()

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

I am new to Kineticjs and not a great javascript coder so I am hoping to get some help with this example.
http://jsfiddle.net/pwM8M/

I am trying to store the x axis on doors so when a redraw unrelated to the doors is done they don't go back to the default position. (multiple types of doors and windows too)

Each form element can have multiple quantities (more than one door) so I need a way to store/retrieve the data currently contained in the alert on jsfiddle.

I did some research but have come up empty.  Can anyone help with what I have provided?

```
       function OH(x,y,w,h) {
        var oh = new Kinetic.Text({
            x:x,
            y: y,
            width: w*scale,
            height: h*scale,
            stroke: wtc,
            strokeWidth: 1,
            fill: 'brown',
            fontSize: 6,
            fontFamily: 'Calibri',
            padding:4,
            text: w+' x '+h+' OH\n\n<- DRAG ->',
            align: 'center',
            textFill: 'white',
            draggable: true,
            dragConstraint:'horizontal',
            dragBounds: {
                left:xoffset, right: xoffset+width+length-(w*scale)
            }
        });
            oh.on('dragend', function(e) {
                alert(oh.getPosition().x);
            });
            window.south.add(oh);
    }
```

Thanks,

Comment: Can you clarify your question or your fiddle please? The 'Click Me' button completely redraws the canvas, you actually call remove children on the layers and re-initialise them, so there's no reason for the doors to retain their position. What other redraw events do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed sized 40x40 rectangle here in which i am using dragging function. try this

```
 var box = new Kinetic.Rect({
                    x: parseFloat(area.size.x),
                    y: parseFloat(area.size.y),
                    width: 40, //parseFloat(area.size.width)
                    height: 40,
                    fill: area.color,
                    stroke: 'black',
                    strokeWidth: 1,
                    opacity: 0.6,
                    id : area.id + id,
                    draggable: true,
                    dragBoundFunc: function(pos) {
                        // x
                        var newX = pos.x < 0 ? 40 : pos.x;
                        var newX = newX > _self.canvasWidth - area.size.width ? _self.canvasWidth - area.size.width : newX;
                        // y
                        var newY = pos.y < 0 ? 40 : pos.y;
                        var newY = newY > _self.canvasHeight - area.size.height ? _self.canvasHeight - area.size.height : newY;

                        return {
                          x: newX,
                          y: newY
                        };
```

Use this function

```
box.on('dragend', function() {
            _self.draw = false;
            _self.dragArea(area, box);
        });
```

and try this to play with x y coordinates

```
dragArea: function(area, box){
        if(box){
            $$('#' + this.formId + ' [name="areas[' + area.id + '][size][x]"]').first().value = parseInt(box.attrs.x);
            $$('#' + this.formId + ' [name="areas[' + area.id + '][size][y]"]').first().value = parseInt(box.attrs.y);

            area.size.x = parseInt(box.attrs.x);
            area.size.y = parseInt(box.attrs.y);
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new array before the function, like so:

```
 var xArray = new Array();
```

then inside your function

```
    oh.on('dragend', function(e) {
       alert(oh.getPosition().x);
       // ADD NEW ITEM TO ARRAY, STORE X POSITION
       xArray.push(oh.getPosition().x);
    });
```

and so all the x values get stored in the array.
If you need to clear the array, you can simply create a new one again with the same name.
And you can iterate through it with a loop if needed.

updated:
http://jsfiddle.net/pwM8M/2/